# Mean Stack Multer

Tags: mean, multer

```
app.post("/upload", multer({dest: "./uploads/"}).array("uploads", 12), 
function(req, res) {
res.send(req.files);
});
```

Please help how to use it in a app.ts, routes.ts and base.ts system

I have used it like this. But getting error: zone.js:2935 POST http://localhost:3000/upload 404 (Not Found)

```
// routes.ts
router.route('/upload').post(valuationCtrl.image);

// base.ts
image = (req, res) => {
res.send(req.files);
}

// app.ts
app.use(multer({dest: './uploads/'}).array('uploads[]', 12));
```